# Как из спарсенной страницы записать данные в словарь

Tags: python, парсер, синтаксис

Спарсилась страница с сайта.
В переменной находится и HTML и JavaScript данные.

```
    import requests # модуль для парсинга
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #модуль для парсинга

s = requests.Session()
loging = s.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, params=None)
soup = BeautifulSoup(loging.content, 'html.parser')
```

Как эту часть спарсенной страницы записать в словарь? По виду эта часть данных - словарь. Но записать в реальный словарь ,что бы получить данные по ключу не получается.

```
{"response":{"cheap":"0",
               "expensive":"0",
               "items":[
                         {"productIndex":"0",
                         "sku":"KA90IVI20R","type":"shop","title":"Холодильник Side by Side","isInComparison":false,"comparable":true,"productsInComparisonSize":0,
                          "sku":"KA90IVI20R","type":"shop","title":"Холодильник Side by Side","isInComparison":"false","comparable":"true","productsInComparisonSize":"0",
                          "headers":["iQ500","Холодильник Side by Side","","177 x 91 cm","Inox-easyclean","KA90IVI20R"],
                          "price":{"value":164990.0,"displayValue":"164 990,00 ₽"},"stockStatus":{"trafficLight":"green","text":"[G11]","buyable":"true","permanentlyNotAvailable":"false"},
                          "link":"/fater/outlet/KA90IVI20R?breadcrumb=",
                          "productImage":{"src":"//media3.123.com/Product_Shots/{width}x{height}/MCSA00762608_E6797_KA90IVI20G_407519_def.jpg","alt":"KA90IVI20R"},
                          "hookline":"Холодильник coolDuo серии iQ 500 типа \"side-by-side\" с технологией NoFrost, дополнительно оснащен дозатором для воды и льда.",
                          "keyBenefits":["Многопоточная система охлаждения multiAirflow обеспечивает равномерное распределение воздуха и охлаждение на всех уровнях холодильника.","Технология noFrost защищает от образования инея и избавит вас от необходимости размораживать холодильник.","Холодильник шириной 70см - существенное увеличение полезного объема для хранения продуктов.","Функция superFreezing понижает температуру на заданный промежуток времени, чтобы быстрее заморозить только что добавленные продукты.","Функция superCooling, или 'суперохлаждение', уменьшает температуру на заданное время,"]
                         }]
               }
   }
```

Мне нужно по ключу title получать данные и записывать в переменную . Пример: ключ -  "title" , значение ключа - "Холодильник Side by Side"

Answer (score 0):

Вы вероятно неправильно пользуетесь применением класса `BeautifulSoup`, но чтобы прямо ответить на ваш прямой вопрос, внутренний словарь получите применением

```
["response"]["items"][0]
```

непосредственно за имя внешнего.